# Descriptive Diagram Customizing

Tags: tikz-pgf, smartdiagram

I hope you are well. I have a request for changing the tikz descriptive smart diagram according to my needs. The following  code generates a descriptive diagram in tikz:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{no shadow/.style={
     every shadow/.style={
         fill=none,
         shadow xshift=0pt,
         shadow yshift=0pt}
 }}
 \tikzset{description/.append style={top color=\col,bottom color=\col,
 minimum height=6.5em,no shadow},
 description title/.append style={top color=\col,bottom color=\col,
 minimum height=6.5em,no shadow}}
 \smartdiagramset{descriptive items y sep=7em,
     set color list={red!40,blue!35,orange!40,cyan!50}}
 \smartdiagram[descriptive diagram]{
     {Models,{Choose the electrical sources models}},
     {Sizing, {Define a sizing module able to desgin an infrastructure based on 
             \begin{itemize}
                 \item [--] meterological data
                 \item  [--] load
     \end{itemize}}},
     {Management, Define a management module able to provide an optimal power profile for each step of the negotiation},
     {Validation, Experiment these both modules to ensure the reliability of the system}}
\end{document}
```

[image: descriptive diagram]

I wanna change this normal diagram to a more interactive one, as you can find them in PowerPoint. The design I am interested to have is something like the following one:

[image: file]

So I would be happy if anyone can help me toward my aim.

Cheers

Moh

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A possible solution with `tcolorbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[4][]{%
        enhanced, width=9cm, height=2cm,
        fontupper=\small\sffamily,
        fonttitle=\large\sffamily\bfseries\slshape,
        leftupper=1.5cm,
        colback=white,
        colframe=white,
        colupper=white,
        title=#2,
        attach title to upper={\\},
        underlay={\fill[#4] (frame.north west)--([xshift=-5mm]frame.north east)--(frame.east)--([xshift=-5mm]frame.south east)-|cycle;},
        overlay={\node[circle, minimum size=2cm, line width=1mm, draw=white, fill=#4, font=\Huge, text=white] at (frame.west) {#3};},
        #1, }
    
\begin{document}
\begin{mybox}{Company Description}{\faIcon[regular]{lightbulb}}{green!50!blue}
This slide is 100\% editable. Adapt it to your needs and capture your audience's attention.
\end{mybox}
\begin{mybox}{Text Here}{\faIcon[regular]{handshake}}{gray!80!green}
This slide is 100\% editable. Adapt it to your needs and capture your audience's attention.
\end{mybox}
\begin{mybox}{Company Description}{\faIcon[regular]{cog}}{green!50!blue}
This slide is 100\% editable. Adapt it to your needs and capture your audience's attention.
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent mwe...and job...very nice.

Comment: Impressive and awesome

Comment: Dear Ignasi
Although it seems so useful to me, I couldn't use it because of fontawesome5 package. It needs XeLaTeX for compilation which removes some of my pdf images from my slides. Can you help me in this regard?

Comment: I compiled my code with pdflatex (miktex over windows) and there is no problem with fontawesone5. In any case, just use the logos that you want or any other font.